# Cannot import Django modules in IPython Notebook

Tags: django, import, module, ipython

I'm starting my IPython Notebook from my vagrant server as follows:

```
ipython notebook --ip='*'
```

When I try to import a Django module, I get the `ImproperlyConfigured` exception:

> ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are
>   not configured. You must either define the environment variable
>   DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing
>   settings.

From the normal Shell, I just run `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=web.settings` and then I can load Django modules from any Python interpreter, however, this hasn't worked with a notebook.

I tried running the following in the notebook, to no avail:

```
!export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=web.settings
!DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=web.settings
```

So, how do I set environment variables in IPython Notebook so I can import Django modules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use `os.environ`:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "web.settings")
```

I guess the "!export" way does not work because it spawns a subprocess to execute those commands, and a child process does not affect the environment of its parent